# Use change of variables to find solutions

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Use change of variables to find solutions to

$$ x^3 \frac{dy}{dx}=yx^2-y^3 $$

Which should I substitute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

If  $f(x,y)$ is a [homogeneous function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function) of order $0$, then ODE $$y'=f(x,y)$$ is a [homogeneous ODE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_differential_equation) of first order and it can be solved by setting $u=\frac{y}x$.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

- This is a Bernoulli equation.
- Divide both sides by $-\dfrac{1}{2} x^3 y^3$
- Let $v =  \dfrac{1}{y^2}$
- Substitute and solve (you will use an integrating factor after the substitution).

**Spoiler**

> $y(x) = \pm \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{2 \ln x + c}}$